# Need to change url and params from jquery

Tags: jquery, html, url, routes, jsrender

HTML:

```
<a class="col-lg-12" href="{{:~url(name, type)}}" data-toggle="tooltip">

$.views.helpers({
        url: function (name, type) {
            return encodeURI("@Url.Action("index", "home", new { id = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"]})");
        }
```

I need to refresh this param id from jquery. And I don't want to use any dummy value and replace it from jquery. Because id may be anything so I couldn't replace with jquery from dummy value.

I tried like below.

```
$("a").attr("href", '<%= Url.Action("index", "home", new { id= ' + $("a li.active").attr("data-value")}) %>');
```

But this is not working.  How to change this param value dynamically from jquery ?

Comment: how not working is it?

Comment: It just forms <a class="col-lg-12" href="<%= Url.Action("index", "home", new { id= 7676 }) %>" data-toggle="tooltip"> I tried load() also. But not woking.